# How to save a predicted image in Amazon Sagemaker?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, amazon-sagemaker

In my `inference.py` I have the following:

```
def output_fn(prediction, content_type):
    assert content_type == 'application/json'
    mask = prediction['mask']
    mask = np.where(mask==2, 255, mask)
    mask = np.where(mask==1, 128, mask)
    trimap = mask.astype(np.uint8)
    trimap_image = Image.fromarray(trimap).resize((prediction['w'], prediction['h'])).convert('L')
    trimap_image.save(prediction['save_path'])
    return json.dumps(['Image saved!'])
```

How can I change `prediction['save_path']` to save it in a s3 bucket?

I have it as `prediction['save_path']=='test.png'` but I cannot find the image anywhere.

Adding to the question: is there a way to return the image as a png or a Numpy array?

This is how I deploy it:

```
predictor = model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type=instance_type,
    serializer=JSONSerializer(),
    deserializer=JSONDeserializer(),   
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the type of inference job, you have 2 options you can follow to fulfil your requirement.

#### 0. Upload during inference (less correct)

This is the easiest method, but less clean. In fact, you make a step that should not be included in the inference. The sagemaker inference has the task of producing a result and giving it in response when the model is invoked. Saving an output is postponed to [batch transform jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html).

By using boto3 (you may need to install it from requirements.txt) within your inference script, you can proceed to invoke the [API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html) to make any upload of any file to any allowed bucket.

E.g.:

```py
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3') # instantiate S3 client 

def output_fn(prediction, content_type):
    # ...
    s3.meta.client.upload_file(file_name, 'YOUR_S3_BUCKET_NAME', 'DESIRED_S3_OBJECT_NAME')
    # ...
    return json.dumps(['Image saved!'])
```

#### 1. Using post-processing job (proper way)

This approach is cleaner, but requires a subsequent component downstream of the inference.

You can use batch transform to save the tensors/bytearray and immediately afterwards a small post-processing job ([Amazon SageMaker Processing in general](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_processing.html)) to convert all the outputs of the previous job into images.

From an architectural point of view, this is the most correct solution as you can easily specify parameters as storage buckets. And this is a task that must be configurable and external to the model endpoint.

This diagram should make the architecture clearer:
[image]